# Can Keycloack replace dap authentication?

Tags: ldap

Sorry but it doesn't accept "hi everyone "

I have several apps which are authenticated by ldap. can keycloack replace this authentication with ldap? and in this way I do not touch to the configuration Of applications ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can read this article https://wjw465150.gitbooks.io/keycloak-documentation/content/server_admin/topics/user-federation/ldap.html

By default Keycloack copy your ldap data but you can choose keycloack use your ldap data :

By default, Keycloak will import users from LDAP into the local Keycloak user database. This copy of the user is either synchronized on demand, or through a periodic background task. The one exception to this is passwords. Passwords are not imported and password validation is delegated to the LDAP server. The benefits to this approach is that all Keycloak features will work as any extra per-user data that is needed can be stored locally. This approach also reduces load on the LDAP server as uncached users are loaded from the Keycloak database the 2nd time they are accessed. The only load your LDAP server will have is password validation. The downside to this approach is that when a user is first queried, this will require a Keycloak database insert. The import will also have to be synchronized with your LDAP server as needed.

Alternatively, you can choose not to import users into the Keycloak user database. In this case, the common user model that the Keycloak runtime uses is backed only by the LDAP server. This means that if LDAP doesn’t support a piece of data that a Keycloak feature needs that feature will not work. The benefit to this approach is that you do not have the overhead of importing and synchronizing a copy of the LDAP user into the Keycloak user database